# React function with onClick event throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDelete' of undefined" in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm currently trying to learn React from this [Youtube Tuorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUPWpXsmuaM&index=11&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i0_2FF-WhtRIfIJ1lXlTZR), however, they are outdated (made in 2016).

**Expected result**

If I click on a `<span> x <span>`, the browser console should display a `console.log("helloo")`

**Issue:**

My current issue is, that after i transpiled my react code, chrome developer console log throws this error:
[image]

**This is my filetree:**

[image]

**This is my index.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import TodoItem from './todoItem'; 

class TodoComponent extends React
  .Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        todos: ["clean up", "walk doggo", "take nap"]
      };
    }
    render() {



      return (
      <div>
        <h1>The todo list:</h1>
        <ul>
          <TodoItem todos={this.state.todos}/>
        </ul>
      </div>);
    }

  }

  ReactDom
  .render(<TodoComponent />, document.querySelector(".todo-wrapper"));
```

**And my todoItem.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {

  handleDelete(){
    console.log("Hellooo");
  };

  render() {

    let todos = this.props.todos;

    todos = todos.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{item}</span>
          <span className="item-remove" onClick={this.handleDelete}> x </span>
        </div>
      </li>);
    });

    return (<React.Fragment>{todos}</React.Fragment>)
  };
}
```

I've been using Stackoverflow, reddit and Google to solve this issue, but most results, who show up, are explaining why "this" is not accessed within the function and is solved by binding it within the constructor. However, I'm not using any this within the function, i just want to console.log("hello") to see if it works.

Thanks for the help and time taken!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That, my friend, is because the callback that you pass to the map is not 'bound' to your class TodoItem. And why is that ? it is because you are passing a plain anonymous function to your map.

Use the arrow syntax instead so that the callback that you pass to the .map Array method be automatically binded to the this inside your render method (which is binded to your component):

`todos = todos.map((item, index) => {
      return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{item}</span>
          <span className="item-remove" onClick={this.handleDelete}> x </span>
        </div>
      </li>);
    });`

EDIT : You can console.log(this) inside the map's callback function to check that this is equal to the global object when you are using the function() { } syntax

UPDATE :

If you don't want to use an arrow function you can put your this inside a variable and use it from your callback like :

```
var myComponent = this;

todos = todos.map(function(item, idx) { /*...*/ onClick= 
{myComponent.handleDelete} }
```

Or declare a method on your component, bind it, and pass it as a callback function :

```
class TodoItem extends ... {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    }
    renderItem(item, idx) { /*...*/ }

    render() {
        todos = this.state.todos.map(this.renderItem);
    }
```

Comment: This works too!
But is there no other way than using the the arrow function? I mean a more native, not recently released way.

Comment: Okay, don't know what the heck happend here, but I tried the   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }
And it didn't work in the first place, but did now.... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Update: I know what the issue was. It only works if i use the todos.map((item, index) => {...}) and not todos.map(function(item, index){...})

Comment: Yes that's what i told you, 'That, my friend, is because the callback that you pass to the map is not 'bound' to your class' :p Have a great dat

Answer (score 3):

`todos.map(function(item, index) => { });`

OR

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleDelete() {
    console.log('helo');
  }

  render() {
    let _this = this;
    let todos = this.props.todos;
    
    todos = todos.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        <li>
          <div className="todo-item">
            <span className="item-name">{item}</span> 
            <span className="item-remove" onClick={_this.handleDelete} > x </span> 
          </div> 
        </li>
      );
    });
    
    return (
      <div>{todos}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App todos={["clean up", "walk doggo", "take nap"]} /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: The second solution works, however the first solution doesn't because of the "function"

Comment: Edited to a runnable example, waiting for approval.

Answer (score 0):

In the class TodoItem

bind the method in the constructor or use the fat arrow notation.

```
export default class TodoItem extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
 }
 handleDelete(){
  console.log("Hellooo");
 };
.
.
.
}
```

Or just use fat arrow like:

```
<span className="item-remove" onClick={()=>this.handleDelete}> x </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The results you found are correct. The this they refer to is the **this**.handleDelete.

When the onClick is called, the context is not provided, because you do not use the arrow function when using your map.

Arrow function pass the context, classic anonymous functions do not.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Just found out the actual problem: Having `function` inside that `map` prevents the use of `this`. But you still need to `bind()` that handler or use arrow functions even after changing that map function to arrow function.

Here's a working example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let list = [1, 2, 3]; //Can take from props
    list = list.map(item => {
        return (<div onClick={() => console.log(`Item ${item} Clicked`)}>{item}</div>)
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

In this example, I wanted the clicked div's to show an alert window with the clicked number, so the onClick prop becomes `onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}`

And if you just need to see the `console.log`, I can recommend you this: 
     console.log('helooo')}> x

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let list = [1, 2, 3]; //Can take from props
    list = list.map(function(item, index) {
        return (<div onClick={() => console.log('heloo')}>{item}</div>)
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

This will never work because a function is it's own object, so `this` refers to that function instead of your class:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
      console.log('helooo');
  }

  render() {
    let list = [1, 2, 3]; //Can take from props
    list = list.map(function(item, index) {
        return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</div>)
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

### Conclusion

1. `.bind()` your handler, or change it to arrow function.
2. Your `todo` mapping needs to be done with an arrow function. Or, see Rohan Veer's answer which copies the reference of `.this` into a variable

I'm just here to provide a working runnable example

Comment: Appreciate your time taken, however, as you might guess, do I want to use that function later for other reasons as just console logging hello. Console logging hello is currently just used to debug the issue and see where the culprit is, which means your solution provided is correct but not useful as it's not accessing a function outside that map.

Comment: Well the culprit is just that, `this` in `function` blocks refers to its own (think of it as it's own `class`). So Rohan Veer's answer will work, or change your `map`ping to use arrow function (though you will need to bind for this one).

Comment: even when i bind the handler, it wont work e.g. "todos = todos.map(function(item, index){...}).bind(this)"